# How to find exact date range from list of date ranges by entering single date

Tags: c#, linq

I want to find the date range which falls in input date, following is structure

```
public class Duration
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}


var durations = new List<Duration>();
var duration1 = new Duration()
{
    StartDate = new DateTime(2017, 08, 1),
    EndDate = new DateTime(2017, 08, 10)
};
durations.Add(duration1);
var duration2 = new Duration()
{
    StartDate = new DateTime(2017, 08, 5),
    EndDate = new DateTime(2017, 08, 10)
};
durations.Add(duration2);
var duration3 = new Duration()
{
    StartDate = new DateTime(2017, 08, 5),
    EndDate = new DateTime(2017, 08, 6)
};
durations.Add(duration3);
```

Now I want to find duration which is closest to the entered date for list of  `<Durations>` with `LINQ` or `for-loop`

My expected result for `currentDate=new DateTime(2017, 08, 7);` is `duration2`

Comment: You better make a `Dictionary` of `DateTime`

Comment: You mean the `StartDate` is closest or the `EndDate` is closest? You have to be more specific. Should `EndDate` be *after* `CurrentDate`?

Comment: both start and end date also closest.

Comment: But then it would be duration3, since 2017-08-06 is the closest of all start and end dates. So what makes duration2 the expected one?

Comment: first its YYYY MM DD format, and date 7 is not fits in duration3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to check if the currentDate is within the start and end dates of each range. For the ones that meet that condition, you calculate the "closeness" adding both distances. When you find one lapse(gap) smaller tan the previous, you save its index... and voilá

```
 int lapse = Integer.MaxValue;
 int counter = 0;
 int index = 0;
 foreach (d in durations) {
     if (((d.StartDate <= currentDate) && (d.EndDate >= currentDate))) {
         int newlapse = ((currentDate - d.StartDate).TotalDays + (d.EndDate - currentDate).TotalDays);
         if ((newlapse < lapse)) {
             lapse = newlapse;
             index = counter;
         }
     }    
     counter +=1;     
 }
 return durations(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the middle of interval to be closest:

```
durations.OrderBy((d) => Math.Abs(d.EndDate.Ticks + d.StartDate.Ticks) / 2 - currentDate.Ticks).FirstOrDefault();
```

If you need the start of interval to be closest:

```
durations.OrderBy((d) => Math.Abs(d.EndDate.Ticks - currentDate.Ticks)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

As D le mentioned above

- First check if currentDate is within the start and end dates
- Second  select the duration with the minimal difference between start end end date

I used a nuget package called morelinq which gives nice extensions methods like MinBy:

```
var result = (from d in durations
              where (d.StartDate <= currentDate && d.EndDate >= currentDate)
              select d).MinBy(d => d.EndDate - d.StartDate);
```